# Shape doesn't show all text

Tags: excel, shapes, vba

I need to create shapes labelled with a number but the shape doesn't display the whole number.

For example, where the number is 1 to 9 it displays, but for 10 to 19 it shows just 1.

I don't want to change the radius it have to be the same.

```
Sheets(xRiS).Select
Dim textRectangles As Shape
Dim radius As Integer
radius = 15

Set textRectangles = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, (Range("D13").Left - radius / 2), _
    Range("D13").Top - radius / 2, radius, radius)

textRectangles.Name = "Groups " & i
textRectangles.TextFrame.Characters.Text = i
textRectangles.TextFrame.VerticalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter
textRectangles.TextFrame.HorizontalAlignment = xlHAlignCenter
textRectangles.TextFrame.Characters.Font.Size = 9
textRectangles.TextFrame.Characters.Font.Name = "Georgia"
textRectangles.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(220, 105, 0)
textRectangles.Fill.Transparency = 0.5
```

This is the current result:

[image]

This is the result I want:

[image]

How can I configure the shape to display the number where the number is 10-19?

Comment: Change the Text Alignment property to Middle Centered (if it is not already), and you may need to adjust the font size.

Comment: in textRectangles.TextFrame how can I make it middle centered, the size is 9 so if i put 5 it will be unreadable

Comment: *how can I make it middle centered* use the macro recorder to get an idea of how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of theoretical options, but neither seem like they are going to work with `radius = 15` and `textRectangles.TextFrame.Characters.Font.Size = 9`.

First is `textRectangles.TextFrame.AutoSize = True` which resizes the shape to fix the text - however, this is going to expand the `radius` significantly.

Second is `textRectangles.TextFrame2.AutoSize = msoAutoSizeTextToFitShape` - however, this only works if the minimum value is `radius = 33`.

You may have to consider increasing the radius.

Comment: the radius should be the minimun and dont change , so it looks good Why it's realisable manually and not programmatically ? 33 is big if I have a lot of points

Comment: Yes - the best sounding property setting `.TextFrame2.AutoSize = msoAutoSizeTextToFitShape`won't work for all configurations :(